# Eclipse: could not construct GCS client

Tags: eclipse, google-cloud-platform

I followed the instructions on here: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse to set up eclipse with google cloud platform.

When trying to create a new dataflow project, I get an error message:

"Could not construct GCS client using default credentials.
Have you authenticated with 'gcloud auth'?

See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/ for more"

I have downloaded and installed and initalized the cloud sdk...

Please advise,

Thanks for your help
Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run this in a shell:
`gcloud auth application-default login`

That will open a window in your browser to perform the authentication.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much that solved it. best regards

Comment: You're welcome! Consider upcoming if that helped you, that will help others find the answer as well.